# Calculate number of weeks between 2 specific dates in snowflake/sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the week number for a year

Generally we can use below weekofyear (default year which take from Jan-1st to Dec 31st) function to get the week number for the date which we passed

```
select (weekofyear("@date_input")) as week_number,date_input from dual

output-

week_number date_input
40          2020-10-01
40          2020-10-04
.
.
1           2021-01-04
.
.
.
39          2021-09-30
```

but here my requirement is the weekofyear should start from Oct 1st to Sep 30th when we pass the date

```
my desired output-

week_number date_input
53          2020-10-01
1           2020-10-04
.
.
13          2021-01-04
.
.
.
52          2021-09-30
```

so to achieve my above desired output I'm using below sql logic and where Im adding 3 month to the date we passing and finding the week number from that date

```
select (weekofyear(dateadd(month,3,"@date-value")))
```

This above sql works fine for 2021-10-01 to 2021-11-27 and from 2021-11-28 to 2021-12-06 the week number is showing 9 for 9 days where same week number count should be exact 7 days where its coming for 9 days

The reason is when we use dateadd 3 months for 2021-11-29 and 2021-11-30 the 3+ months is Feb-2022 and where Feb don't have 29th and 30th so its showing same week number for those 2 dates as well(2021-11-29 and 2021-11-30)

So I need help that is there any logic we can use for my requirement ?

Please advice on how to proceed with this logic

Note - Edited the question

Comment: Re-read your question and correct things like "..... week number for 30- sep-2021 is 52/53".    Also add some sample data because you statement  is unclear here: "as Feb dosen't have 29th and 30th (...) and its shows week number as 9 for 9 days"

Comment: for more info see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe your problem is solved when adding 13 weeks, and not 3 months ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Please add a specific list of sample inputs and desired outputs, and please ask a new question if this one has lost visibility by then.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely seeing the documented behavior for `dateadd()`

> When date_or_time_part is year, quarter, or month (or any of their
> variations), if the result month has fewer days than the original day
> of the month, the result day of the month might be different from the
> original day.

I'd say you are running into the nuances of `weekofyear()` and why the `WEEK_OF_YEAR_POLICY` parameter exists.

For these reasons, I don't think you can use `weekofyear()` and will instead have to implement a UDF and perhaps define your own semantics for how to define whether or not 10/1 is part of week 1

It is helpful to provide a little test SQL like

```
with d as (select $1 weeknum, $2::date  mydate from (values (53, '2020-10-01'), (1, '2020-10-04'), (13, '2021-01-04'), (52, '2021-09-30')))
select *,weekofyear(mydate)+13,weekofyear(dateadd(week, 13, mydate)),weekofyear(dateadd(month, 3, mydate)) from d
53  2020-10-01  53  53  53
1   2020-10-04  53  53  1
13  2021-01-04  14  14  13
52  2021-09-30  52  52  52
```